# C++ reading integers from file

Tags: c++

I am trying to read integers from a txt file, right now I put two integers in the txt file on the same line (4 and 8), but my program keeps outputting 0 and 0. What am I doing wrong??

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    std::ifstream fin;
    fin.open("Q2.dat");

    int x,y;
    fin >> x >> y;
    std::cout << x << y ;


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: at bare minimum, you should check the file to be opened (`good()`).

Comment: I know the file is opened, I took out that if statement to really simplify the code for the sake of the question.

Comment: Works for me. What are the exact contents of the file? And double check that it is opening it.

Comment: can the fact that I am using xcode and a mac mess things up for me? The exact contents of the file are (4 8 ).

Comment: If your file begins with (, no wonder you can't read it as an int.